# Is it OK not to answer personal questions on a job interview

Tags: human-resources

Interviewers sometimes ask questions that make me uncomfortable: what is your hobby, what is your favorite fiction book, what is your relationship status, what is your greatest weakness, what is your position on Ukrainian conflict etc. Shall I look bad if I outright refuse to answer any personal questions?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: [How should I respond to an inappropriate question in a job interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/8899) [How can I respond to "Why shouldn't we hire you?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20338)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is completely OK not to answer political or personal questions; pretty much anything that is work UNrelated subjects.

A good answer would be:

> I prefer not to discuss this subject now.

Or

> I am not that political (or the subject) and I tend to stay away from it.

However, "*What is your favorite fiction book?*", or "*what is your greatest weakness/strength?*", are NOT that personal.

Comment: "what is your greatest weakness" is important for the job, even. I wouldn't skip answering that one.

Comment: "what is your greatest weakness" is important for the job, even. I would have a prepared answer for that one ready.

Comment: "what is your greatest weakness/strength?" is the hallmark of an unexperienced interviewer, and as a senior in the industry, there are so much more interesting things to talk about in my CV.

Comment: Inexperienced interviewer or not, it's a relatively common question and refusing to answer it is not going to get you hired.

Comment: You are making the assumption that people only want to work for perfect companies. Having an inexperienced interviewer may make working there less desirable, but it's not a reason to automatically discard opportunities with the company.

Comment: I did NOT say ignore or pass or dodge the "_what is your greatest weakness_" question! Why the downvotes tornado?

Comment: @SandraK probably because you *didn't* say dodge it.  There can be some very odd views here sometimes!

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro i don't believe you

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of looking bad on the interview.

Comment: @RichardU yes it does, and it states that it is OK (means will not look bad). If you disagree, then that does not make this answer not an answer.

Comment: For the fiction book or greatest weakness, are they personal at all?  Aren't they just standard stressor questions?

Comment: @RichardU Maybe you had to read the last part of my answer?

Comment: @SandraK I did, you said "not that personal", not "Not personal", I'm sorry, it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

These are not really personal questions, and you should be prepared to answer them.

With the political questions, demonstrate a knowledge of it, but be non committal.

> Well, I understand that the conflict in the Ukraine goes back quite a bit as the region has had a complex relationship with divided loyalties in the region.

And yes, it will look bad if you just refuse to answer, that's never good form.

Asking about a hobby is them wanting to know that you have interests outside of work, if you don't have one, you should.

Asking about a book is another stressor question.  I like to answer with something like

> Well, I've been reading the sword of truth series, because I love the character of Richard.  No matter what difficulties he faces, he never gives up and always finds creative solutions.

(see what I did there?)

"What is your greatest weakness?" is fairly standard, and you should have an answer that is either something you are working on, or is not related to your position.

I'm a coder and never have to speak or do presentations in my jobs, so I usually say something like.

> Well, I'm really not that good at public speaking, which is why I  prefer this line of work.

or

> I've noticed in the past that I've tended to get obsessed with details, but knowing that, I always try to take a step back and consult with my coworkers or management if I find myself in that situation.

The only one that's worth avoiding is the relationship one.  They shouldn't ask that, and if they do you can decline to answer that with:

> Well, once I'm on board and part of the team for a while, I'd be happy to discuss that with you, but right now, that's a bit awkward.

If they turn you down for avoiding that last one, you don't want to work there anyway.